# New website URL not picked up by discovery/content service

Tags: web8, topology-manager

I have an existing SDL Web8 website running on `http://mysite` which is all working fine. I added a new URL for my website (to test https) to Topology Manager using

```
Set-TtmWebsite -Id mysiteid -BaseUrls @("http://mysite","https://mysite")
```

My understanding is that it should be possible to access the site on `https://mysite` almost immediately, however its not possible, and also I cannot retrieve any data via the following content service query:

```
http://c:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='https://mysite')
```

I tried restarting the Discovery and Content services, and also recycling the Topology Manager web application pool, but no change.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this further, or on any steps I may have missed?

UPDATE

I'm not sure if this is related, but when I try to run Sync-TtmCdEnvironment, I get an error in the Discovery Service - the following is from the log file:

```
2016-11-16 13:11:20,016 ERROR ODataRendererActor - Unexpected exception during response rendering - org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 'failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.jpa.JPAConfigurationItem.using, could not initialize proxy - no Session'
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.jpa.JPAConfigurationItem.using, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at ......
```

UPDATE 2

I don't know why, but it has just started working. Another user managed to add some new URLs just fine, and they I tried again and mine also worked fine. Very mysterious. The error with  running Sync-TtmCdEnviroment remains however..

Comment: yes i should be immediately. i have not tried https before. but for http it works fine. also do Get-TtmWebsite shows your both wesbsites?

Comment: The PowerShell scripts for TTM (Topology Manager) update the TTM and then somehow something (I guess the TTM service) will sync with the Discovery service. Since you cannot run `Sync-TtmCdEnvrionment` does not work I suspect TTM cannot sync either when you use `Set-TtmWebsite`. Fix the `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment' error and mysite will be available on the CD side.

Comment: Looks like your Discovery Service is borked.